# JMeter - How to loop through "bsh.shared" ArrayList in a single Thread Group?

Tags: performance, arraylist, jmeter, beanshell

I have a BeanShell PostProcessor under the setUp Thread Group.
I put the ArrayList into the "bsh.shared" namespace like:

```
List personIdsList = new ArrayList();
...
bsh.shared.personIds = personIdsList;
```

I know how to read the value via __BeanShell function as:

```
${__BeanShell(bsh.shared.personIds)}
```

And I want to loop through this array in other Thread Group. (${personId} - it should iterating value from list)

[image]

Could you, please, tell me how to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be using [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) together with the [Counter](http://How%20to%20Use%20a%20Counter%20in%20a%20JMeter%20Test) test element like:

1. Add While Controller to your 2nd Thread Group and put the following expression into the "Condition" area:

   ```
   ${__BeanShell(Integer.parseInt(vars.get("counter")) < bsh.shared.personIds.size()-1,)}
   ```
2. Add Counter as a child of the While Controller and configure it as follows:

   - Start: `0`
   - Increment: `1`
   - Maximum: `${__BeanShell(bsh.shared.personIds.size()-1,)}`
   - Reference Name: `counter`
3. Refer the "current' person ID as `${__BeanShell(bsh.shared.personIds.get(Integer.parseInt(vars.get("counter"))),)}` 
   where required

Demo:
[image: JMeter Beanshell Counter Demo]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution!
It is very helpful, but I have one question.
During 1st iteration counter value is unknown. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Instead of Integer.parseInt(vars.get("counter")) use ${counter}

So your BeanShell expression will look like:
${__BeanShell(bsh.shared.personIds.get(${counter})),)}